# Convert freehand path to shape

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I am trying to allow the user to draw a free hand shape, then using a best guess algorithm, convert the free hand to an actual shape.  I hope to have it pretty simple at first.  Probably just ellipses and rectangles.  I'm trying to find a good starting point.  Is there a library available that does this.  Or a set of algorithms that would be useful.  Any help to get me started would be great.  I'm having trouble finding the proper terms to search for.

Comment: look up "vectorisation algorithm". Your case is simplified by the fact you don't need to tweak the level of detail (too big / too imprecise).

Answer (score 1):

[googling "pattern recognition geometric shapes handwritten"](http://www.google.cl/#q=pattern+recognition+geometric+shapes+handwritten) returns hits including [A Simple Approach to Recognise Geometric Shapes Interactively](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.37.2973)